# Created GIF for recorded video in IOS is very large amount of data. How to reduce it before upload?

Tags: ios, gif

Currently I am using "Regift" library that converts a recorded video into GIF format.

I am successfully create GIF, However the main problem  is that my gif data is very high . I am converting only 6 second video and it generate around 60 MB GIF data.

So any way to reduce it large amount of data without loosing quality.